# Can you break an iPad by keeping it in a warm place?

Tags: ipad

I left my iPad mini 2nd gen in my car last night and it was fully functional, today I went to get it out and it is really hot outside 30C or 86F and sunny and inside of the car feels like sauna. iPad seems to be of and not responding if I try to switch it on. I thought it might run out of charge even though it would display charge me icon. I plug it in to charge and it is still not showing a sign that it is charging. Is it possible that it could have been boiled inside of car or has anyone had anything similar in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say if you had let the iPad cool down, but the inside of a sealed car on a hot sunny day can go over 125°F.

If it *has* cooled down and *still* does not work, perhaps it has been baked to death. You might want to take it to an Apple Store, if convenient.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP661?locale=en_US):

Environmental Requirements:

- Operating ambient temperature: 32° to 95° F (0° to 35° C)
- Nonoperating temperature: -4° to 113° F (-20° to 45° C)
- Relative humidity: 5% to 95% noncondensing
- Maximum operating altitude: 10,000 feet (3000 m)

Comment: it is normal temperature now. Guess it did bake to death. Poor bitten apple

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store anyway & tell them what happened.